# Inverse muon decay on Mandl shaw- Help on $W$ boson propagator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, feynman-diagrams, scattering-cross-section, electroweak

[image]

Hello, I cannot understand why here the other term of the propagator of $W$ boson $k^{\alpha} k^{\beta}/m_{W}^{2}$ is not present, and how/if this absence is linked to the fact that we neglect terms proportional to $m_{\mu} m_{e} / m_{W}^2$.
Thank you.

Comment: Few readers have that text: can you excerpt that Fig 16.8 here?

Comment: Are you 110% ***sure***  you don't have $k^2 \ll m_W^2$ ??

Comment: Maybe this is because, in the standard model, we can use the $R_\xi$ gauge fixing $\xi=1$? You are forced to use the gauge fixing method because before SSB, the $\text{SU}(2)\times \text{U}(1)$ bosons are massless.

Comment: In Fig.8 there is just the representation of the scattering. I am sure that book does not specify to use k^2 << m^2_{w}. You can find the exercise here: https://fizika.pmf.kg.ac.rs/files/predmeti/teorija%20polja%20i%20simetrije%20u%20fizici/Mandl,%20Shaw%20QFT.pdf pag. 379

Comment: It cannot be limit k^2 << m^2_{w}, otherwise in the formula for the amplitude in the book k^2 should be absent.

Comment: “Difficult to detect” means absent? Have you worked out the kinematics?

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring irrelevant prefactors, the amplitude of the process $e^-(p) \nu_\mu(q) \to \mu^-(p^\prime)\nu_e(q^\prime)$ is proportional to     $$\bar{u}(q^\prime)\gamma^\alpha (1-\gamma_5) u(p) \bar{u}(p^\prime) \gamma^\beta (1-\gamma_5)u(q) \frac{\eta_{\alpha\beta}-k_\alpha k_\beta/M_W^2}{k^2-M_W^2},$$ where $k=p-q^\prime=p^\prime-q$. Concentrating on the second term (the one with $k_\alpha k_\beta$), the relevant expression is given by  $$ -\frac{1}{k^2-M_W^2} \frac{1}{M_W^2} \, \, \bar{u}(q^\prime) k \! \!\! / (1-\gamma_5)u(p) \, \, \bar{u}(p^\prime) k \! \! \! / (1-\gamma_5) u(q).$$ Using $p \! \! \! / u(p) = m_e \, u(p)$, $\, \bar{u}(q^\prime) q^\prime \! \! \! \! \! / =0$, $\, q \! \! \! / u(q)=0$ and $\bar{u}(p^\prime) p^\prime \! \! \! \!\! / = m_\mu \, \bar{u}(p^\prime)$, one finds $\bar{u}(q^\prime) k \! \! \! / (1-\gamma_5) u(p) = m_e \, \bar{u}(q^\prime)(1+\gamma_5)u(p)$ and $\bar{u}(p^\prime) k \! \! \! / (1-\gamma_5) u(q) = m_\mu \bar{u}(p^\prime)(1-\gamma_5) u(q)$, showing that the second term in the amplitude is indeed suppressed by a factor $m_e m_\mu/M_W^2$.